# Python equivalent to 'hold on' in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, graph, matplotlib

Is there an explicit equivalent command in Python's matplotlib for Matlab's `hold on`? I'm trying to plot all my graphs on the same axes. Some graphs are generated inside a `for` loop, and these are plotted separately from `su` and `sl`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in np.arange(1,5):
    z = 68 + 4 * np.random.randn(50)
    zm = np.cumsum(z) / range(1,len(z)+1)
    plt.plot(zm)
    plt.axis([0,50,60,80])

plt.show()

n = np.arange(1,51)
su = 68 + 4 / np.sqrt(n)
sl = 68 - 4 / np.sqrt(n)

plt.plot(n,su,n,sl)

plt.axis([0,50,60,80])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you mean `plt.hold(True)`?

Comment: Possible dupe of [multiple-plot-in-one-figure-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254472/multiple-plot-in-one-figure-in-python/21254861)

Comment: @Cody Piersall - It might work for others, but apparently not for my example.

Comment: It should be pointed out the `hold=True` is the default.

Comment: I hope this helps since this worked for me: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670101/matplotlib-ion-function-fails-to-be-interactive)

Comment: `plt.hold(True)` is deprecated in latest version of `matplotlib`. Use plt.show() in the program

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just call `plt.show()` at the end:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axis([0,50,60,80])
for i in np.arange(1,5):
    z = 68 + 4 * np.random.randn(50)
    zm = np.cumsum(z) / range(1,len(z)+1)
    plt.plot(zm)    

n = np.arange(1,51)
su = 68 + 4 / np.sqrt(n)
sl = 68 - 4 / np.sqrt(n)

plt.plot(n,su,n,sl)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Note: This doesn't work in the case of interactive input from the command line. Works fine if run within a script.

Answer (score 24):

You can use the following:

```
plt.hold(True)
```

Comment: This function is deprecated, Any alternative solution like this?

Comment: @Jyotirmay The hold function in matplotlib does not serve any purpose and was hence deprecated. pyplot always acts as if `hold` was set to True anyways.

Answer (score 20):

The `hold on`  feature is switched on by default in `matplotlib.pyplot`. So each time you evoke `plt.plot()` before `plt.show()` a drawing is added to the plot. Launching `plt.plot()` after the function `plt.show()` leads to redrawing the whole picture.

Comment: How would you get around this when using IPython?

Comment: use backend %matplotlib inline and all plt.plot() within one cell will be output in the same frame. If you put plt.show() between plt.plot() functions within a cell it will create more frames, new one for each plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

check `pyplot`  docs. For completeness,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#evenly sampled time at 200ms intervals
t = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

# red dashes, blue squares and green triangles
plt.plot(t, t, 'r--', t, t**2, 'bs', t, t**3, 'g^')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use plt.sca(ax) to set the current axes, where ax is the Axes object you'd like to become active.

For example:

In a first function:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
for i in np.arange(1,5):
    z = 68 + 4 * np.random.randn(50)
    zm = np.cumsum(z) / range(1,len(z)+1)
    plt.plot(zm)
    plt.axis([0,50,60,80])

plt.show()
```

In the next function:
def function2(...., ax=None)

```
if ax is None:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
else:
    plt.sca(ax)

n = np.arange(1,51)
su = 68 + 4 / np.sqrt(n)
sl = 68 - 4 / np.sqrt(n)

plt.plot(n,su,n,sl)

plt.axis([0,50,60,80])
plt.show()
```