# Python -Two figures in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two python plot functions:

```
def plotData(data):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    results_accepted = data[data['accepted'] == 1]
    results_rejected = data[data['accepted'] == 0]
    ax.scatter(results_accepted['exam1'], results_accepted['exam2'], marker='+', c='b', s=40)
    ax.scatter(results_rejected['exam1'], results_rejected['exam2'], marker='o', c='r', s=30)
    ax.set_xlabel('Exam 1 score')
    ax.set_ylabel('Exam 2 score')
    return ax
```

And second function is:

```
def plot_boundry(theta,x):
    """
    """
    plt.figure(1)
    px = np.array([x[:, 1].min() - 2, x[:, 1].max() + 2])
    py = (-1 / theta[2]) * (theta[1] * px + theta[0])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(px, py)
    return ax
```

And i am calling both :

```
#####PLOT ######
ax = plotData(df)
ax = plot_boundry(opt_theta, x)
```

I get 2 separate plots:
[image]

[image]

I got 2 separate picture.How Do I add two plot into one.
Both the plot should be one plot.

Comment: Just pass in the `ax` that is returned from `plotData` to `plot_boundary` and use that to `plot`. Or create the `ax` outside of the functions and pass it in to both.

Comment: after passing what to be done.where to change

Comment: Use that `ax` instead of `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you want exactly:

1. If you want the two figures overlayed, then you can call [`hold`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465988/python-equivalent-to-hold-on-in-matlab)`(True)` after the first, then plot the second, then call `hold(False)`.
2. If you want the two figures in a single figure, but side by side (or one over the other), then you can use [`subplot`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplot_demo.html). E.g., call `subplot(2, 1, 1)` before plotting the first, then `subplot(2, 1, 2)` before the second.

Comment: @Aman Not exactly - you used `subplots`, not `subplot`. Note that in `subplots`, you [seem to be missing a `2` parameter](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html).