# Merge two numpy arrays into one matplotlib image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img1 = np.load('abc.npy')
img2 = np.load('xyz.npy')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img1)
ax.imshow(img2, alpha = 0.1)
```

I want to merge two numpy arrays to a single image using matplotlib. This piece of code just shows the last image img2. How can I create a image where img1 and img2 are overlaid.

Comment: This works as expected for me

Comment: If the opacity is not set then you will not see the first images since the second is directly over it. Do you want to see these two images side-by-side [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465988/python-equivalent-to-hold-on-in-matlab)?

Comment: Maybe one of the images is all white? Maybe one image is much larger than the other?

Comment: Even if I set the alpha of both images to < 0.5, I can just see the image I call last. The numpy arrays have different size. I want to see them on top of each other integrated in one image. The image which is shown is the smaller one.

Comment: A possible workaround: `ax.imshow(0.9*img1 + 0.1*img2)` (adjusting the ratio of `img1` to `img2` as needed).