# Animation of xy data in matplotlib

Tags: python, file, animation, matplotlib

So essentially I have a few numbered files like `output_0000.dat ... output_1999.dat` that each correspond to a consecutive timestep in the simulation of a wave on a string. The files contain the `x` and `y` positions for each point on the string at that timestep.

My goal is to plot these files one after another to make an animation, ideally using `matplotlib` but other software will also do.

If you could also direct me to a helpful tutorial, I'll be very greatful.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a better question for http://stats.stackexchange.com/. The Cross validated forum, more data enthusiasts there!

Comment: have you looked at the matplotlib examples? [here is a good one](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/basic_example.html) for your problem. [or another one](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/simple_anim.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation tutorial suggested by @tom are probably the ideal solution, however the simplest way to do what you want is to use interactive [plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670101/matplotlib-ion-function-fails-to-be-interactive) with filenames padded by [zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string) and numpy's [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html),

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.show()

for i in range(2000):

    filename = "output_{0:04d}.dat".format(i)
    print("printing file = ", filename)
    xy = np.genfromtxt(filename)
    x = xy[:,0]; y = xy[:,1]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

You may need to add `delimiter` to genfromtxt depending on the format of the data in your files.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!