# matplotlib plot doesn't appear even after editing the backend and using pylab.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a simple script to test a plot in matplotlib but no window showing the figure appears. On reading other questions on stackoverflow, I've done the following to resolve this:

- installed PySide using [these](http://pyside.readthedocs.org/en/latest/building/linux.html) instructions.
- edited matplotlibrc file with these two lines:

  ```
   backend      : Qt4Agg
   #backend.qt4 : PySide        # PyQt4 | PySide
  ```

  so that the command `python -c 'import matplotlib; import matplotlib.pyplot; print(matplotlib.backends.backend)'` now yields `Qt4Agg` whereas before it gave `agg`
- included the `pylab.show()` command. So the set of commands that I now tried in the python interpreter after installing Pyside, and editing the matplotlibrc file look like this:

  ```
    import pylab
    pylab.ion()
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)
    plt.plot(x,y)
   [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fcef627cdd0>]
   pylab.show()
  ```

  However, the plot still doesn't show. Could anyone please help me with this? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox with python2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use your code the plot actually flashes on the screen, but closes immediately. Placing an `input()` function at the end might help you with debugging it:

```
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


pylab.ion()
x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
pylab.show()
tin = input("Test Input: ")
```

And removing the `pylab.ion()` actually keep the plot on the screen. This gives you another hint. There are already some good answers why this is happening. E.g.:

- [Matplotlib ion() function fails to be interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670101/matplotlib-ion-function-fails-to-be-interactive)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know what just happened, but I tried the commands in the order you posted above, that is imported all the libraries first, and as soon as I typed plt.plot(x,y) the plot popped up. And its staying on the screen. Hmm. So, its working now.

Comment: Actually, it works outside the virtualenv, but inside virtualenv its still causing problems. Will investigate further.

Comment: I guess if you need a pause after each plot. The information in the link I posted says that a `plt.pause(1)` is needed between plots. At least a millisecond apparently.

Comment: Yes, I just tried that. It works! :) Thanks so much!

Comment: Great. Glad i could help.