# Can matplotlib and readchar work simultaneously?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to be able to move a dot around the matplotlib plot using the w, a, s, and d keys without having to hit enter each time after I type the letter. This works using readchar.readchar(), but then the plot does not show up. What am I doing wrong?

```
""" Moving dot """
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import readchar

x = 0
y = 0
q = 0
e = 0
counter = 0
while 1 :
    #arrow_key = input()
    arrow_key = readchar.readchar()
    print(x,y)
    if arrow_key == "d" :
        q = x + 1
    elif arrow_key == "a" :
        q = x - 1
    elif arrow_key == "w" :
        e = y + 1
    elif arrow_key == "s" :
        e = y - 1
    plt.ion()   
    plt.plot(x,y, "wo", markersize = 10)
    plt.plot(q,e, "bo")
    plt.xlim(-10,10)
    plt.ylim(-10,10)
    x = q
    y = e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem in your code is that the readchar.readchar() returns binary strings. You need to decode it to utf-8: `arrow_key = readchar.readchar().lower().decode("utf-8")`

I'd say it's best that you do the `plt.xlim()` and `plt.ylim()` limitations before the `while` loop.

My `plt` froze if I wasn't using `plt.pause()`. I added multiple  `plt.pause(0.0001)` to get the code working. reference: [Matplotlib ion() function fails to be interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670101/matplotlib-ion-function-fails-to-be-interactive)

Also, you required user input in your code before showing the plot. I changed it to the plot showing before user input.

Changing `x` to be `q` and `y` to be `e` is best done before input. It being after the input caused the previous plots to show for me.

**EDIT:** as FriendFX suggested below, it's good to define the plots as variables (`pl1 = plt.plot(x,y, "wo", markersize = 10)` and `pl2 = plt.plot(q,e, "bo")`) and delete them after use to not fill the memory. `pl1.pop(0).remove()` and `pl2.pop(0).remove()`

Full repaired code below. Note that in startup you may lose terminal window focus, which is critical for the input.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time # you didn't use this, do you need it?
import readchar

x = 0
y = 0
q = 0
e = 0
plt.xlim(-10,10)
plt.ylim(-10,10)

counter = 0 # you didn't use this, do you need it?
while(1):
    plt.ion()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
    pl1 = plt.plot(x,y, "wo", markersize = 10)
    pl2 = plt.plot(q,e, "bo")
    plt.pause(0.0001)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
    x = q
    y = e

    arrow_key = readchar.readchar().lower().decode("utf-8")
    print(arrow_key)

    if arrow_key == "d" :
        q = x + 1
    elif arrow_key == "a" :
        q = x - 1
    elif arrow_key == "w" :
        e = y + 1
    elif arrow_key == 's' :
        e = y - 1
    print(q, e, x, y)
    pl1.pop(0).remove()
    pl2.pop(0).remove()
```

Comment: Nice one. Depending on what the OP needs, it may also be helpful to delete existing plot points with `lines.pop(0).remove()` as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4981918/897968), where `lines` is a variable storing the output of one (or both) of the `plt.plot()` calls, e.g. `line = plot.plot(q,e, "bo")`. Also, I don't think the `show()` call is required in the loop.

Comment: @FriendFX You're right. Added your suggestions and deleted the `plt.show()`