# Why does my code crash with any mouse click?

Tags: python, function, csv, crash, infinite-loop

Ok, so I was just going for proof of concept here and I did manage to get this working. (Discalimer: I have been told this is something that should be using threading but I'm new to python and that might be out of my grasp currently) Its a program that reads a csv file and plots the data, then repeats. I have a program writing the csv and I am able to see the plot being created in real time which is exactly what I wanted. What I don't undestand fully is why its crashing. I understand my code is pretty sloppy but any mouse click anywhere on the screen or even just tabbing to a different screen causes my program to stop responding. Is there an easy fix to this?

```
import csv 
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

filename = 'sample.csv'
callback = ''
global counter
results =''
counter = 0
timestr = []
thickness = []
thick = []


def csv_process(filename, callback, delay=1):

class waiter:     
    def __init__(self, fd, delay=1):
        self.fd = fd
        self.delay = delay
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self): 
        while True:
            line = fd.readline()
            if line:
                return line
            time.sleep(self.delay)
            results()
    def __next__(self):  # bc im using Python3.4
        return self.next()
with open(filename, "rt") as fd:
    rows = csv.reader(waiter(fd, delay), delimiter=',')
    for row in rows:
        callback(row)
    results()

def process_row(row):

global time, thickness, counter, timestr, thick, results
counter = counter+1
if counter > 5:    #csv file has 5 lines of header data

    hrs = float(row[0][11:13])   #had a hard time getting the data into a format I could plot
    mins = float(row[0][14:16])
    secs = float(row[0][17:22])
    timestr.append(hrs*1440+mins*60+secs)
    thick = float(row[3])
    thickness.append(thick)
    return thickness, timestr

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = axes.plot([], [], '.')
plt.ion()

def results():
    global line
    line.set_data(timestr, thickness)
    plt.show()
    while 1:
        plt.draw()
        axes.relim()
        axes.autoscale(True,'both',True) 
        axes.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
        return line

if __name__ == "__main__":
     csv_process(filename, process_row)
```

Sample csv data:

```
% Comments:  
% Samples Averaged: 1
% Factor: 1
% Units: um
% A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
2015-08-14 13:09:52.809000,1,0,1257.57,,,,0,0,-1
2015-08-14 13:09:52.824000,1,0,1257.57,,,,0,0,-1
2015-08-14 13:09:52.839000,1,0,1257.57,,,,0,0,-1
2015-08-14 13:09:52.854000,1,0,1257.57,,,,0,0,-1
2015-08-14 13:09:52.869000,1,0,1257.57,,,,0,0,-1
2015-08-14 13:09:52.884000,1,0,1257.57,,,,0,0,-1
2015-08-14 13:09:52.899000,1,0,1257.57,,,,0,0,-1
```

Comment: Just curious, did you try a smaller csv file? If so, was the outcome the same?

Comment: Yeah, I used several different size files. A csv that has been created ~10 seconds prior will crash in the same manner as one with days worth of data, but neither crashes unless I interact with the computer.

Comment: I was hoping it was because you had a large data set but now I am not sure. Maybe you should learn threading and see if you have the same issue once you incorporate threading into your code.

Comment: Finally figured it out, I had to add a pause in my while loop. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480167/matplotlib-ion-and-subprocesses?rq=1) was where I got tipped off that I might need to use it..