# Not able to zoom data using Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to make a real time graph using matplotlib and have tried it successfully. But there is one issue what I faced. I was not able to zoom the data while the data is shown on graph. That is blocking my observation. See the following is my code:

```
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(30,10)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
#plt.show(block=False)
plt.show()
first_time = 1       
def main():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
        server.listen(8)  # max backlog of connections

        print (('Listening on {}:{}').format(bind_ip, bind_port))


        while True:
            client_sock, address = server.accept()
            print (('Accepted connection from {}:{}').format(address[0], address[1]))
            client_handler = ThreadWithReturnValue(
                target=handle_client_connection,
                args=(client_sock,)  # without comma you'd get a... TypeError: handle_client_connection() argument after * must be a sequence, not _socketobject
            )
            client_handler.start()
            y_forecast_pred,candles = client_handler.join()
            ax1.clear()
            ax2.clear()
            if(first_time):
                line1, = ax1.plot(y_forecast_pred[:,0],color='blue', label='Y Forecast 1 first buffer',marker=".")
                candlestick2_ohlc(ax2,candles.o.values[seq_len:],candles.h.values[seq_len:],candles.l.values[seq_len:],candles.c.values[seq_len:],width=0.6,alpha=0.7)
            else:
                line1.set_ydata(y_forecast_pred[:,0])
                candlestick2_ohlc(ax2,candles.o.values[seq_len:],candles.h.values[seq_len:],candles.l.values[seq_len:],candles.c.values[seq_len:],width=0.6,alpha=0.7)
            ax1.legend()
            ax1.relim()
            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(0.001)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        server.close()
```

The screen gets hanged up. Please help me in getting the plotting smoothly and capable of zooming in real time.

Comment: are you using an IDE?

Comment: No I am not using IDE. Simple Notepad. Its socket script which I am trying to use.

Comment: no experience on non-IDE :( maybe this helps! https://stackoverflow.com/a/35219904/9754169

Comment: I tried it. It didn't worked for me. You can see my code may resemble similar stuff